# No puedo publicar una versión beta en Google Play

Tags: google-play

Ayer publiqué una aplicación en *Google Play* en versión **producción** y debido a unos errores de rendimiento he tenido que "despublicarla". Después de esto he decidido publicar una versión **beta** cerrada para testear la aplicación (soy nuevo en esto de publicar y debido a mi desconocimiento primero publiqué en producción y no al revés).

El problema viene cuando desactivo la versión de **producción** e intento publicar solo la versión **beta**. La consola de Google no me deja guardar los cambios y mucho menos publicar.

Adjunto un screenshot de mi *Google Developer Console*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que no puedes usar esa app sólo en beta/alpha porque ya fue publicada en producción (tiene que ver con el Developer Distribución Agreement). Una vez que una app ha sido publicada en producción debe tener siempre un apk disponible.

Para publicar **sólo** en beta/alpha tendrías que remover la app existente y publicar una nueva con un nuevo nombre de paquete.

Puedes encontrar más info aqui:
[Descubrimiento y visibilidad de las aplicaciones](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=es-419#ts=3280770%2C6034687)

Comment: Me imaginé que era algo de eso. Por otro lado, cuando dices "con un nuevo nombre de paquete", ¿te refieres al "com.compañía.nombredelaapp"?

Comment: Exacto, ese mero

Comment: Pues muchas gracias @DanielSanchez, me ha quedado todo muy claro.